# Samsung Smart TV Trigger remote key

Tags: javascript, button, triggers, television

I need to trigger the STOP button of the remote control, how can I do that?.

I need it because my VIDEOJS player is not listening the remote buttons until I press the STOP button and I can't figure out why.

I found this answer here:

```
"sf.scene.get('Main').handleKeyDown(sf.key.STOP);"
```

But the app doesn't found the "sf" variable.

Comment: Honestly I would like to help you but I find hard to understand what you are asking for

Comment: Is not sf the main Smart TV api? I think you have to include the needed scripts

Comment: I need to trigger the stop button of the remote control (in my app) just Like you trigger a key in jquery. "$("input").trigger(e);"